# point closest to $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 -8x-4y-6z =30$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

on the x axis find the point closest to $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 -8x-4y-6z =30$

$x^2 + y^2 +z^2 -8x-4y-6z =30$ is a sphere, that we know, but I cant see a way to connect this to the requested task...

Comment: Find the centre of the sphere, and you're nearly done.

Comment: To the end Arthur suggests, complete the square separately in each coordinate $x, y, z$.

Comment: What if it was a disc, instead of a sphere: could you find the point in the plane that is closest to, say, $x^2+y^2 - 8x - 4y = 21$?

Comment: I see that I wrote "point on the plane" when I meant "point on the $x$-axis".  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The $x$-axis actually touches this sphere, so are you sure the question is right?

On the $x$-axis, $y=z=0$. So consider $$x^2-8x=30$$ This has two solutions: $$x=4\pm\sqrt{46}$$ So there are two points that touch this sphere: $$\left(4\pm\sqrt{46},0,0\right)$$

Comment: thats what the question says..

Comment: although from what you say here the question doesn't have any sense really...

Comment: A simple typo could make it a more interesting problem. For instance, if it were $-30$ in place of $30$.